# A couple has two children. At least one is a boy. What is the probability that the couple has one child of each sex?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

I assume that the question assumed that the probability of having a boy is 50% and the probability of having a girl is 50%

So I'm confused because this seems like a really easy probability question. If they already have a boy. The probability that they have a girl is just $.5$ isn't it?

But the book says that the probability is $2/3$

This seems completely illogical to me because then that would assume that the boy to girl birth ratio is $1$ to $2$ which doesn't seem right at all.

What am I misinterpreting here? Is the book wrong?

Comment: Are you familiar with conditional probability?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure what use it would be here... The given would be that they have at least one boy, but what do I do with that info?

Comment: The question essentially asks for $P(A|B)$, where $A$ is the event that one child is a boy and the other is a girl, and $B$ is the event that at least one child is a boy.

Comment: The we know the situation is one of these three equally likely cases:  $BB$, $BG$, $GB$.  So what can you conclude from that?

Comment: Ah damn, Order matters! Thank You, I see it now. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can

Comment: Statistics and probability are often counterintuitive. It's best to expect such results.

Comment: @Bill Billwater regarding David G. Stork's comment: actually it doesn't. But the probability comes out the same as if it did.

Comment: The words "at least" make no sense in this classic probability problem. The problem goes "A couple has 2 children and one of them is a boy. What is the probability that the other one is also a boy?". Using the sample space laid out by David, there are three options of which two are favorable

Comment: "at least" 1 as in 1 or 2, instead of none (0) or both(2) or exactly 1 (1) boys. So there isn't a "the other one" because you don't know 'which' of the two mentioned is for sure a boy.  If you haven't done so, check out the flawed probability "frog-licking" video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpwSGsb-rTs, which is somewhat counterintuitive for opposite reasons as this one.

Comment: "order" doesn't matter but specificity does. The difficulty is the *language*.  We don't really have any way of distinguishing between the hypothetical question but they *are* two different beings.  If we told one to go the garage and the other to the attic, or if we painted one blue and the other green or we indicated which one was older and which was younger we have one or the other is a boy. The probability they aren't both boys is 2/3. But when we don't indicate a way to distinguish we linguistically identify one by what we are told. "One is a boy" and the other is the other one.

Comment: @imranfat  I disagree entirely. At least one is a boy means exactly what it says.  It is not the case that there are 0 boys; it is the case there are one boy or there are two boys.  That makes perfect sense.  And if we *did* state the problem as you did.  "One of them is a boy" then we have specified a specific child as "the" boy.  He's a boy, he likes cookies and his is currently in the living room watching tv while his sibling is the bedroom doing homework.  The probability the other child in the bedroom doing homework is a girl is *exactly* 1/2. But that wasn't the question.

Comment: This is a famous problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox

Comment: , including evidently on this forum: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=boy+girl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know the situation is one of these three equally likely cases: , , . So what can you conclude from that?

Answer (score 1):

By careful of what is *said* and what it means.

The question said "at least one" was a boy; not "a specific child" is a boy.

There are four equally likely possibilities.  They have two boys, they have two girls, they have a boy and a girl, or they have a girl and a boy.

If we know they have at least one boy that rules out having two girls.  That leaves three equally likely scenarios.  They have two boys, they have a boy and a girl, or they have a girl and a boy.

Now had they question been, the couple have two children and one of them is a boy, what is the probably the other one is a girl, you'd be correct.  But that wasn't the question.  The question was (could be paraphrased as) the couple of two children, given that one or the other, or maybe both are boys, what is the probability that they are one (either one) is a boy and the other is a girl.